# Cannot able to call a api from gke private cluster. It is showing Connection timed out (<ip>:443)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, gke-networking

I have created a private cluster in a region.Then we deployed a NAT router in that region (which has a static ip).

Now this cluster sent traffic through this ip. So we whitelisted this IP to call our API. We used this pod as a self hosted agent in azure devops pipeline.

But when we are trying to access our API using this agent (pod), we are getting `Name or service not known`. So we tried calling our api with the client IP instead of DNS name, which is now throwing `Connection timed out (<ip address>:443)` .

P:S: I have created a firewall which will allow ingress and eggress to this ip in port 443.

Please help me to know what's went wrong

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would need a little more detail on exactly what you are doing here and what you have actually deployed in GKE.  And are you saying the pod running in GKE is failing to call an API hosted outside of GKE?

Comment: yes.. it was outside gke.. but we have found the issue that the api is expecting call from organitation's account